# How my docker container can have network access to the outside and the user defined bridge (other containers) at the same time?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Here is my issue.

I have my application containerized into different containers which I launch with docker-compose. So all the containers are connected through a bridge which isolate them from the outside world. (docker-compose automatically creates this bridge for the project)

But my issue is one of my containers needs to communicate with outside world. Say one of the containers is based on an Python image and I need to dynamically call 'pip install' commands as part of my application logic.

But once all the containers are in an isolated bridge my python based container (just an example) cannot talk to outside and perform pip install commands.

I know you cannot have bridge and host network together. But, from the design perspective what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried making outbound calls from your container?  Even with a non-default bridge network it should work fine.  (And you probably shouldn't run `pip install` from a running container; anything it installs will get lost as soon as the container's destroyed.  Put it in a Dockerfile instead.)

Comment: Apparently my question was kind of a wrong question, because containers do have access to the outside world. You are right